# Update data after x amount of hours, In Sql Server / or Wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, database, linq-to-sql

I have a program that uses a licence system for its users.  Now I have an integer column LicenceDays in my database, and I would like to decrement that value every 24 hours by 1. So lets say for example my LicenceDays is at 4, after 24 hours make an update to the database and it will be at 3.

Now I don't get how I would go about that.  Where do I start?  Can I achieve this in Sql Server itself, or could I use some sort of code in my WPF C# Program?  I'm using LINQ to SQL to access my database.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Why not have a license start date.  Subtract the current date from the the license start date and if it's less than x # of days, it's expired...

Comment: you can create an sql server stored procedure and schedule it via sql server job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a recurring SQL task, probably the easiest and most maintainable solution would be to create a job within SQL Server itself.  You can write your SQL statement that decreases "LicenseDays" by 1, and schedule it to run every 24 hours.  You can even schedule, update and start/stop this using the GUI within SQL Server Management Studio.

More info on SQL Server jobs:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx

Comment: Hi, Ive been checking into this, And I dont think they have SQLServer Jobs on SQL 2008, As that is what I run.]So I cannot achieve this unless I have SQL 2012?

Comment: @MarkMackanga They do have jobs in SQL 2008.  Are you running Management Studio?  It's under SQL Server Agent -> Jobs.  This does assume you have SQL Server Agent installed though ...

Comment: Ok I just found out that SQL Express doesnt have the Agent. So atleast now I know what I need so Ill look for a workaround, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.